# Get the attributes and values from xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have following xml file:

```
<ROW>
    <rating>10</rating>
    <answers>Very Satisfied</answers>
    <transaction_date>01/21/2015</transaction_date>
    <date>05/30/2015</date>
    <username>got2bsunny4me</username>
    <link>http://widget.resellerratings.com/store/Amberen/review/#comment8877470</link>
    <comment><![CDATA[my extreme hot flashes became less frequent within a couple weeks, and not as severe.  after 2 months of taking Amberen, I didn't need to take as often.  I've used Amberen before and my hot flashes...]]></comment>
</ROW>
<ROW>
     <rating>10</rating>
     <answers>Very Satisfied</answers>
     <transaction_date>03/23/2015</transaction_date>
     <date>05/18/2015</date>
     <username>musiclvr24</username>
     <link>http://widget.resellerratings.com/store/Amberen/review/#comment8785090</link>
     <comment><![CDATA[Ordering was very easy!  The whole website was very informative and very useful as a health resource.  Thank you very much!]]></comment>
</ROW>
```

Here is my php file to parse xml file.

```
<pre>
<?php

$seller_id = 113;
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://widget.atings.com/widget/snippet/?seller_id=$seller_id"));
foreach($xml->ROW as $row){  
//echo $row,'="',$s,"\"\n"; // to get all rows
 var_dump($row);
   echo '<div class="spans"></div>';
}



//var_dump($xml->ROW) // to get single row
?>
</pre>
```

I need to get each row's attributes and values displayed on newly created divs for each row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If possible add some main tags at start and end of your XML and rest of your code will work fine...

```
<document>
<ROW>
<rating>10</rating>
<answers>Very Satisfied</answers>
<transaction_date>01/21/2015</transaction_date>
<date>05/30/2015</date>
<username>got2bsunny4me</username>
<link>http://widget.resellerratings.com/store/Amberen/review/#comment8877470</link>
<comment><![CDATA[my extreme hot flashes became less frequent within a couple weeks, and not as severe.  after 2 months of taking Amberen, I didn't need to take as often.  I've used Amberen before and my hot flashes...]]></comment>
</ROW>

<ROW>
<rating>10</rating>
<answers>Very Satisfied</answers>
<transaction_date>03/23/2015</transaction_date>
<date>05/18/2015</date>
<username>musiclvr24</username>
<link>http://widget.resellerratings.com/store/Amberen/review/#comment8785090</link>
<comment><![CDATA[Ordering was very easy!  The whole website was very informative and very useful as a health resource.  Thank you very much!]]></comment>
</ROW>
</document>
```

Comment: Your php code will work fine... you can replace `$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://widget.atings.com/widget/snippet/?seller_id=$seller_id"));` with `$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://widget.atings.com/widget/snippet/?seller_id=$seller_id");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclosed some main tags like "ROWS" which enclosed other tags. please check below XML and code to access element value.

```
$xml = <<<XML
<ROWS>
    <ROW>
        <rating>10</rating>
        <answers>Very Satisfied</answers>
        <transaction_date>01/21/2015</transaction_date>
        <date>05/30/2015</date>
        <username>got2bsunny4me</username>
        <link>http://widget.resellerratings.com/store/Amberen/review/#comment8877470</link>
        <comment><![CDATA[my extreme hot flashes became less frequent within a couple weeks, and not as severe.  after 2 months of taking Amberen, I didn't need to take as often.  I've used Amberen before and my hot flashes...]]></comment>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <rating>10</rating>
        <answers>Very Satisfied</answers>
        <transaction_date>01/21/2015</transaction_date>
        <date>05/30/2015</date>
        <username>got2bsunny4me</username>
        <link>http://widget.resellerratings.com/store/Amberen/review/#comment8877470</link>
        <comment><![CDATA[my extreme hot flashes became less frequent within a couple weeks, and not as severe.  after 2 months of taking Amberen, I didn't need to take as often.  I've used Amberen before and my hot flashes...]]></comment>
    </ROW>
</ROWS>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($xml as $row){  
    echo $row->rating;
    echo $row->answers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://widget.atings.com/widget/snippet/?seller_id=$seller_id") or die("Error: Cannot create object");                                
foreach($xml->children() as $child) :

endforeach;

// Load xml file content

$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://example.com/xml.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");


//Get children with foreach.


foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{ $inc = 1;
    foreach($child->children() as $childs){                                 
    foreach($childs->children() as $childss){
    if($inc == 7) :                                             
    if($childss->getName() === 'description') :
    echo '<div class="descriptionOfNisab">'.  $childss . '</div>';
    endif;
    endif;                                              
    }                                   
    $inc ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: please do not provide only code as answer.You should include some explanation too.